# Docker Hello World fails

Tags: docker

I'm trying docker by following the setp by step tutorial mentioned at the docker.io  and I have problems getting it to run:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ jothi$ docker run buntu:14.04 /bin/echo 'Hello world'
2014/09/18 22:10:53 Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.14/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory
My-MacBook-Pro:~ joe$
```

I do not understand this error. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to install Docker. To do that, on OSX, you'll need to first install [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker) (and launch the VM).

Comment: I did install boot2docker, but looks like I'm having problems getting boot2docker to start.